# field enable disable javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two radio button, and I want to show some value on my html page according to value which a user selects in the radio button.

my html file:

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="calenders" value="calendar_details_b2b">B2B
<br>
<input type="radio" name="calenders" value="calendar_details_b2c">B2C
</form>
<div id="calendar_details_b2c" >
   content of B2C
</div>
<div id="calendar_details_b2b">
   content of B2B
</div>
```

here is the JS fiddle which is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0b0xp5xm/9/

Now when I change the Id's , it is not working, https://jsfiddle.net/vjLnou8h/1/

**EDIT**

I have added this code in my rails application _form.html.erb which i am rendering on new.hrml.erb page.

```
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type=radio][name=calenders]').change(function () {
  $('#calendar_details_b2b').css("display","none");
  $('#calendar_details_b2c').css("display","none");
  console.log($(this).val());
  var fieldToShow = $(this).val();
  $("#" + fieldToShow).css("display","block");
  });

});
</script>
```

But It is still not working.

Comment: You are getting an error because of jquery reference not added.

Comment: You need to explain what "still not working" actually means. Are you getting an error? Have you checked the console?

Comment: when I click on the any radio button, the section which is hidden does not appear...ignore the console.log($(this).val()); line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add the JQuery reference, it works just fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/vjLnou8h/2/

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #data_Analysis,
      #study_Design {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="">
      <input type="radio" name="calenders" value="study_Design">B2B
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="calenders" value="data_Analysis">B2C
    </form>

    <div id="study_Design">content of B2B</div>
    <div id="data_Analysis" >content of B2C</div>


    <!-- It's generally better to put your scripts just before the <body> tag closes
         because by the time the browser gets that far, the DOM has been read. Also,
         it can speed up page load times. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      $('input[type=radio][name=calenders]').change(function () {
        $('#study_Design').css("display","none");
     $('#data_Analysis').css("display","none");
     console.log($(this).val());
     var fieldToShow = $(this).val();
     $("#" + fieldToShow).css("display","block");
      });
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so do I need to write javascript function in between <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> my JS function  </script>

Comment: No. That won't work. You need to add: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (or whatever path you are getting JQuery from) prior to your set of `<script>...</script> tags. (FYI make sure you are referencing the correct version of JQuery that you plan to use - See: https://code.jquery.com/ for details.

Comment: Like this--  <script src="source of jquery which you gave me"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> MY CODE </script>

Comment: Yes, but you can leave out `type=text/javascript` - that is no longer needed.

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz Your original question has been answered. Please vote on the answer provided and post a new question if you need to since my answer addresses why your code wasn't working.